# Problems with my "for loops" -- Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I've been trying to create a `for loop` that prints all whole numbers between any two input `integers`.

for example:

if I input 1 and 4, it should print **1,2,3,4** .

However, my current code only prints the final input.(the one labelled "end")

What could be up with my code? Note that the if statement checks to make sure the inputs are valid.

```
{
    int start = Integer.parseInt(startingInput.getText());
    int end = Integer.parseInt(endingInput.getText());

    if (start >= end) {
       hintLabel.setText("Please input valid numbers"); 
    }
    else {
        for (int count = start; count <= end; count++) {
            outputArea.setText(count + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `outputArea.setText(count + ", ");` you are just setting text of your, lets say `JTextArea` because i don´t know, over and over to `count + ,`, you are rather out for `outputArea.setText(outputArea.setText() + count + ", ");`, Or using a `StringJoiner` to create the complete String first.

Comment: Because `outputArea.setText(count + ", ");` will only save the last one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are printing the output to some UI component, and you keep overwriting the previous value :

```
outputArea.setText(count + ", ");
```

You need something like (not sure about the exact method call, since I don't know the type of `outputArea`) :

```
outputArea.setText(outputArea.getText () + count + ", ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this worked great! Are responses normally this fast on StackOverflow? Or did I just get super lucky?

Comment: @3.14ed_Piper ask a   good and well formatted question and u get response super  fast

Answer (score 0):

outputArea.setText(count + ", ");

here every time you pass replace the content of outputArea instead of appending the content

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could first create your `String` then set your box:

```
{
    int start = Integer.parseInt(startingInput.getText());
    int end = Integer.parseInt(endingInput.getText());

    if (start >= end) {
       hintLabel.setText("Please input valid numbers"); 
    }
    else {
        String s="";
        boolean isFirst=true; //used to omit the last ","
        for (int count = start; count <= end; count++) {
            if(!isFirst){
              s+= ", ";
            }
            s+= count;
            isFirst=false;

        }
        outputArea.setText(s);
    }
}
```